# When using `max_value` in Apache IoTDB, why did the result returned `NaN` instead of the only data value included?

Tags: max, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I would like to ask about a schenario that I query data by month in Apache IoTDB. I use the `max_value()` method to query the maximum value, and the result of the query after grouping is not the maximum value, but `NaN`. The last value of our data has data value in it, and the other values are marked as `NaN`. These `NaN` values are inserted manually. I want to know why the maximum value did not returned to be the last data value in the time series?

Answer (score 0):

Any value compared with `NaN` will return `false` result in Apache IoTDB. This means that when initializing the `MAX_VALUE` aggregation, if the first value encountered is `NaN`, then when making `>` judgments, it will always return false, so the aggregation result will be NaN. If the first non-null value encountered is not `NaN`, the aggregation result will be obtained normally. Therefore, if your first value has no value, you can express it as a `NULL` value instead of `NaN` value to avoid your error.